# how can i change backgroundColor Around the button in header react-native

Tags: navigation, header, react-native

how can i change background Color Around  the button in header?

Please see the photo first
[image: icon with blue background]

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
      options={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
        },
        safeAreaInsets: { left: 20 },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
        headerShown: true,
        title: '',
        headerBackTitleVisible: true,
        // headerTransparent: true,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button
            name="bars"
            size={25}
            color="red"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'yellow',
              width: 45,
              borderRadius: 50,
              paddingRight: 0,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              marginLeft: 30,
            }}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);
```

Comment: You'd need to create a **custom header** if you wanna customize this area...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `backgroundColor` prop of the `Icon.Button` component to set the color to what you need.

For example you can do the following to set the color to red.

```
headerLeft: () => (
  <FontAwesome.Button
    name="bars"
    size={25}
    color="red"
    backgroundColor="red" // set background to match navbar
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      width: 45,
      borderRadius: 50,
      paddingRight: 0,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      marginLeft: 30,
    }}
    onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
  />
),
```

Find an working example in this Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/header-button

Answer (score 0):

On your `Icon.Button` simply set the `underlayColor`, like this - I used `transparent` in this example:

```
<Icon.Button
  name="bars"
  size={25}
  color="red"
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    underlayColor="transparent" // <-- customize it here
    width: 45,
    borderRadius: 50,
    paddingRight: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 30,
  }}
  onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
/>
```